# How to push data to array and return in callback function?

Tags: sails.js

I am building a web app using sails. I have a problem in my service. I want to push mapped data to array and return to controller.

Here is my code.

```
getPortlet : function(callback){

    var myExampleCriteria = [
         {year : 2015, month : 4},
         {year : 2015, month : 3},
         {year : 2015, month : 2}
    ]; 


  Portlet.find().where(myExampleCriteria).exec(function(err, result){
      var portlet = [];
      if(err){ callback(err); }
      else{
            _.map(result, function(data){
                 portlet.push({
                      year : data.year,
                      month : moment().month(data.month-1).format('MMM'),
                      status : data.status
                 });
            });   
            callback(null, portlet);
          }
   });  

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: and what's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, your usage of [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map) is incorrect. You're using it as if it were _.each. Second, I need you to tell me what your actual problem is. What error message are you seeing? If there's no error, what is happening?

Here's the proper way to use map:

```js
getPortlet : function(callback){

    var myExampleCriteria = [
         {year : 2015, month : 4},
         {year : 2015, month : 3},
         {year : 2015, month : 2}
    ]; 


  Portlet.find().where(myExampleCriteria).exec(function(err, result){
      var portlet = [];
      if(err){ callback(err); }
      else{
        callback(null, _.map(result, function(data){
          return {
            year : data.year,
            month : moment().month(data.month-1).format('MMM'),
            status : data.status
          };
        });
       }
   });  

}
```